# How can I take selfie by running a console command on Mac?

Tags: command-line, camera

I know I can take a selfie with the built-in camera via the Photo Booth app. However, is there a way capture an image via command line, in sort of [lolcommits](https://github.com/mroth/lolcommits) style?

Comment: I thought about "taking a selfie while running" and I pictured all sort of horrible accidents…

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is a program called "[ImageSnap](http://iharder.sourceforge.net/current/macosx/imagesnap/)".  You can take iSight photo's by typing the command imagesnap into terminal.

```
All commands:

 USAGE: imagesnap [options] [filename]
Version: 0.2.5
Captures an image from a video device and saves it in a file.
If no device is specified, the system default will be used.
If no filename is specfied, snapshot.jpg will be used.
Supported image types: JPEG, TIFF, PNG, GIF, BMP
  -h          This help message
  -v          Verbose mode
  -l          List available video devices
  -t x.xx     Take a picture every x.xx seconds
  -q          Quiet mode. Do not output any text
  -w x.xx     Warmup. Delay snapshot x.xx seconds after turning on camera
  -d device   Use named video device
```

Just incorporate imagesnap commands into a cron job or workflow of your command.  ImageSnap is also available thru homebrew:

```
brew install imagesnap
```

Comment: It seems it needs full installation of Xcode :-o